# Loop Through an Array and Figure Out Which One Matches A Value Dynamically

Tags: php, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have an array of "Auto Makes" and their respective "IDs" (represented as an integer below).

```
$auto_makes_one = 10;
$auto_makes_two = 11;
$auto_makes_three = 12;

$auto_makes_array = array (
    array("Auto Make One",$auto_makes_one),
    array("Auto Make Two",$auto_makes_two),
    array("Auto Make Three",$auto_makes_three)
);

for ($row = 0; $row < 3; $row++) {

    echo "<p><b>Row number $row</b></p>";
    echo "<ul>";

    for ($col = 0; $col < 2; $col++) {

        echo "<li>".$auto_makes_array[$row][$col]."</li>";

        if ($auto_makes_array[$row][$col] == 12) {

            echo "yes" . "<br>";

        }

    }

    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Using this code, I am checking to see if any values equal 12:

```
if ($auto_makes_array[$row][$col] == 12) {

    echo "yes" . "<br>";

}
```

With the if statement above, if the number matches 12, how do I know which Key it is matching to?

What I mean is... say $auto_makes_three = 12, I would like to then set $auto_makes_three_readable = "Ford"

So in this case I am trying to figure out if its "Auto Make Three" that has the value of 12 or another, and then if it does be able to set the variable $auto_makes_three_readable to "Ford". Then I would like to make the code dynamic so it can automatically do this for "Auto Make One" or "Auto Make Two"

Comment: Where is `$auto_makes_three_readable` and the relations between the numbers and the words (like 12 => "Ford") ?

Answer (score 0):

when you declare an array like this

```
$auto_makes_one = 11;
array("Auto Make One",$auto_makes_one);
```

Know that it is gonna create an indexed array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Auto Make One
    [1] => 11
)
```

If you want to create an associative array with your own keys, declare like this

```
$myArr = array("Auto Make one"=>$auto_makes_one);

 Array
 (
     [Auto Make one] => 11
 )
```

Now since you want the key of the associative array, use

```
$key = array_search('11', $array);
```

which is gonna print

```
Auto Make one
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So lets say it prints out Auto Make one. Then how could I dynamically set a variable $auto_makes_one_readable to a certain value? And then have the code dynamically do the same for say "Auto Make two" where it sets a variable $auto_makes_two_readable to a certain value? In other words, the "one" and "two" are substituted in automatically for the variable name

Comment: Here's an example... Lets say two of the keys have the value "11" like in your example. "11" would represent the auto make "Ford"... so I want to create a new variable for each key where their numbers "one" or "two" are dynamically inserted into the variable name. Then I can have something like "$auto_makes_one_readable = 'Ford'" and "$auto_makes_two_readable = 'Ford'" based on their respective key names